# How to count number of String objects present in class

Tags: java, string

I have one class that has number of a String variable, I want to count all String variables.

```
public class Account {
    
    //objects
//    private String pageAuthenticationNavBar = "xpath:=//div[@class='ng-binding' and contains(text(),'Account Authentication')]";
    private String listAuthMethod = "id:=account-authentication-authentication-methods";
    private String btnContinue = "xpath:=//button[@id='account-authentication-continue']";
    private String btnSkip = "xpath:=//*[contains(text(), 'Send OTP')]/..//*[contains(text(),'Skip')]";
    private String btnSkipNoSMS = "xpath:=//*[@class='skip-sms-auth-container']//*[contains(text(),'Skip Authentication')]";
    private String formAccountAuthentication = "xpath:=//*[@class='global-container authentication-process']";
    private String txtChooseSubscriber = "xpath:=//div[contains(text(), 'Choose Subscriber')]";
    private String txtSubscriberByIndex = "xpath:=(//*[contains(@class,'flex subscriber-item-inside-list')]//*[@class='subscriber-icon'])[INDEX]";
    private String btnSendOtp = "xpath:=//button[starts-with(@class,'auth-continue-button')]"; //id:=account-authentication-send-otp
    private String txtOtp = "id:=smsCodeInput";
}
```

Is there any method, any logic for counting all the String objects?

Comment: You can use reflection to iterate (and filter) fields of a class. But it would be easier to put these Strings into a List or array which makes them countable.

Comment: i dont understand...the number is not constant?? it can change between instances of "Account" class?? what magic is this??

Comment: If I may ask, *why* do you want this?

Comment: I have one package that has a number of classes I want to count String variables of all classes. I am getting class name through Reflection in List and putting every class name  then executing the above code but its accepting String.

Answer (score 0):

As f1sh mentioned in comment, you can use reflection something like below:

```
public class Test{
 String a="";
 String b="";
 String c="";

 public static void main(String[] args) {
 
 int stringCount=0;
        for(Field f : Test.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
            if(f.getType().getName().equals("java.lang.String"))
                stringCount++;
        }
        System.out.println(stringCount);
}
}
```

Output:

> 3

Comment: You should use `equals` rather than `contains`, as this code will also count `String` arrays.

Comment: @MCEmperor, thanks for suggestion, doing edits.